# How to make a custom cursor appear on an entire page and not just one small portion

Tags: css, cursor, markup

**I have seen this, but it does not provide any solution to my programming issues:**
Custom cursor to entire page

**This is the CSS Markup:**

```
body { 
    height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
    background: #000 url('http://1hdwallpapers.com/wallpapers/undead_dragon.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; 
    cursor: url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png'), auto; 
}
div#mask { 
    cursor: not-allowed; 
    z-index: 999; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
a:link { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:visited { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
a:active { 
    color: #F433FF; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    text-decoration: blink; 
}
a:hover { 
    color: #F433FF; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: blink; 
}
#about_me 

div.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 8em;
}
{ 
    width: 355px; 
    float: right; 
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
.contentTitle { 
    color: #fff; 
    background: #000; 
}
.contentModule { 
    color: #FF00FF; 
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
    background: transparent; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
#right_column { 
    float: left; 
    width: 355px; 
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px; 
}
#left_column { 
    width: 210px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    margin-right: 0px; 
    float: left;
}
#pet_panel  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 700px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
    width: 40%; float: left; margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
}
#comment_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    right: 85px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
#tombstone_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 85px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
#user_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 385px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
#wishlist_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    right: 85px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

**This is the HTML Markup:**

```
<div id="about_me" class="contentModule">
    <div class="contentTitle">About Me</div>
    <div class="contentModuleI">my tagline </div> 
</div>
```

**What can I do to make my custom cursor visible throughout my page like the default cursor is?**

Comment: And yes "contentModulel" is spelled correctly. For some reason my code doesn't work without it being spelled that way. :\

Comment: your custom cursor appear on Firefox and looking solution for IE?

Comment: you have some empty definitions and some orphan declarations. For example, #about_me has nothing, while `{ width: 355px; float: right; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; }` belongs to nothing. Fix it and it should work, your cursor code is fine

Comment: Wait do you mean put{ width: 355px; float: right; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; } on #about_me?

Comment: @Fabio: This is the new code:    #about_me 

    div.center {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 8em;
      width: 355px; float: right; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; }

Comment: @Viewer: I also forgot to mention that the wishlist panel has a varying header size upon each refresh.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey: Forgive me. Idk what you mean.

Comment: ` width: 8em; width: 355px;` why repeating `width` twice?

Comment: As per your `question title` `custom cursor` appear on full page and I've gave the solution for that... If you've some different problem you have to ask another question here.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey: You're right, but idk. Should I use 8em or 355px?

Comment: I would suggest if you making a responsive website then you should go for `width in %` and `em` is basically used for `font-size`.

Comment: Ok this worked somewhat I'll have to go over it some more. I might post another question a little later for that though. Thanks all. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display `custom cursor` on full page you have to add CSS like this. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/govuyixequju/1)**.

```
body, html 
{ 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0;
background: #000 url('http://1hdwallpapers.com/wallpapers/undead_dragon.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; 
cursor:url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png'), url('cute25.cur'), help;
}
```

so here explain how it works; `Firefox` and `chrome` are fine with  `.jpg` or `.png` file extension. But to support in `IE`  need a `.cur` file extension. You may convert your image into `.cur` extension. from this **[online tool](http://www.cursor.cc/)**.

**Note: If you need it work also in IE then you have to use cursor `.cur` file extension.**